# Modelio close/crash without messages

Tags: java, jvm, glib, modelio

I'm using Modelio 3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit with Java 1.7.

Sometimes, apparently without a specific sequence pattern, Modelio closes; other times, it doesn't allow to make any type of operations (i.e. when I right click on an element, it doesn't show anything).
I don't know what the problem is. If I launch it from the terminal, it always returns error message like this

> (Modelio 3:10699): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_closure_unref: assertion 'closure->ref_count > 0' failed

or this

> (Modelio 3:10699): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 20104 was not found when attempting to remove it

but the execution continues, so I don't think this is the problem.

Finally, Modelio (or the JVM, I don't know) creates error files in its main directory, but they are very long. Should I post all their content?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: link to the error files
[file1](http://www.mediafire.com/download/z4p2vlla8drvucl/hs_err_pid26148.log)
[file2](http://www.mediafire.com/download/766y1tm6b566mnt/hs_err_pid27247.log)

Comment: Your messages shall be related to a known SWT Issue but it should not be the reason of your close/crash ...

Could you send the error files?

Comment: @RedBeard Thanks for your help. How can I send the files?

Comment: I do not know, a link,  a private message maybe.

Comment: Maybe it is related to : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1245468

Comment: @RedBeard thanks. As I can see, the bug is a duplicate of this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1241101
Thanks again for your help.